# Jetty and Jersey 404 error on an old project

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0, embedded-jetty

As part of my work, I am trying to update some of our services and one is being deployed with Jetty & Jersey. Unfortunately the code is very old (some dependencies are from 2014), and while it is compiling and server starts, whenever I run it from my IDE with `mvn jetty:run` the root directory shows the `Directory /` message correctly whereas for all other URLs I get the error `404 NOT FOUND`.

I don't get any warning/error messages on console and I can't find why it happens. I've searched a lot but the code seems correct, the only thing that is missing is the `web.xml` but I think Jetty is embedded, and I need to mention that this code is already running in production as a JAR.

Below you can see some of the files:

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

The class below is referenced to start the server:
`ApiService.java`

```
import com.simple.api.restendpoint.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpVersion;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.IPAccessHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class ApiService {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ApiService.class);
    
    private static ApiService instance;
    private final Server server;

    private ApiService(){
        //CREATE CONFIG
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<>();
        s.add(restEndpoint.class);      

        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(s);

        //CREATE CONTAINER
        ServletContainer container = new ServletContainer(config);

        //CREATE CONTEXT
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(container),"/*");

        //CREATE RPC SERVER
        QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
        threadPool.setMaxThreads(50);
        server = new Server(threadPool);

        server.setHandler(context);

        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(8080);

        server.addConnector(connector);

        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("testkeystore");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("testkeystore");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("testkeystore");

        // SSL HTTP Configuration
        HttpConfiguration https_config = new HttpConfiguration();
        https_config.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

        // SSL Connector
        ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));
        sslConnector.setPort(Settings.getInstance().getRpcPort());
        server.addConnector(sslConnector);
        
    }

    public static ApiService getInstance() {
        if (instance==null) {
            instance = new ApiService();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            //START RPC 
            server.start();
            server.join();
            log.info("Server started");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //FAILED TO START RPC
            log.error("Error starting server");
        } finally {
            server.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

`restEndpoint.java`

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.container.Suspended;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/v4/restEndpoint")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public class restEndpoint {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(restEndpoint.class);

    private static final String VERSION = "v4";

    private static final ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @GET
    @Path("/getsamplejson")
    public void getSampleJson(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        executors.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String result = veryExpensiveOperation();
                asyncResponse.resume(result);
            }

            private String veryExpensiveOperation() {
                JSONObject sampleJson = new JSONObject().put("test", 0);
                return sampleJson.toString();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any idea why is it happening?
`http://localhost:8080/v4/restEndpoint/getsamplejson` returns `404 NOT FOUND`
`http://localhost:8080/` shows `Directory: /`

Should I try to build it as a JAR and run it through that, instead of using the `mvn jetty:run` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an embedded-jetty instance, started from code.

That is evidenced by the `ApiService` source you have provided.

You cannot use the `jetty-maven-plugin` to manage / start / run that class.

The `jetty-maven-plugin` is exclusively for working with webapps, either as WAR packaged files, or as exploded webapp directories. (webapps will either have a WEB-INF/web.xml and / or Servlet annotated classes within it)

You'll need to start the server using other means that is unique to your project, likely some kind of main class, or testcase, that eventually instantiates the `ApiService` and calls `.start()` on it.